# Batch command to not copy a file if exists and then to delete the file

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, xcopy

I am trying to create a batch file that will Copy files from say d:\temp to c:\temp and if the file already exists on c:\temp to actually delete it from c:\temp, do not attempt to copy that file and continue copying remaining files. Repeat if exists etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
for /r D:\temp %%a in (*) do (
    if exist "C:\temp\%%~nxa" (
        del "C:\temp\%%~nxa" /f /s /q
    ) else (
        copy "%%a" C:\temp
    )
)
```